# memory-wise manipulation of a subview

Tags: objective-c

does this retain my subview twice?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
mapButtons*newButtons=[[mapButtons alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.mapButtons=newButtons;
[newButtons release];

[self.view addSubview:self.mapButtons];

[self.mapButtons addButtons:@"yo"];
```

once it is added to the view hierarchy with addSubview, does it get an additional retain count beyond that retained by the ivar, self.mapButtons?

i want to be able to manipulate this subview easily, hence the ivar; is this a good way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
You mention `memory-wise` so I think it may need some clearing up. Each object has a retain count which is incremented with `retain` and decremented with `release`. When the retain count reaches 0 a `dealloc` message is sent. So when you put an additional retain on an object you are not using anymore memory you are simply incrementing the counter and not doing any kind of duplication.

There are a couple of ways you can grab a reference to a view but the way you are doing it is a good way. An alternative would be to tag the view and retrieve it from `self.view` using

```
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:tagId];
```

I prefer the ivar way e.g. how you have done it (this will change when ARC comes in) but I tend not to worry about the the actual retain count of an object. I concentrate on balancing my retain/releases.

Therefore I use the rule that if it's a local variable I try as far as possible to match my retain/release's within the scope it is defined in. The exception being ivar which are released in `dealloc`

Comment: thanks, it is always re-assuring when another more experienced developer thinks i'm doing something correctly. of course, now that i've learned a lot of this memory management stuff, the introduction of ARC in iOS 5 has me wondering, "huh" ?